# How to store images in android app

Tags: android

I am looking at developing an android app, the app basically is like a grocery list which needs to store an image for each grocery item. What is the best way to store images for the app. since there is a huge list of groceries there will probably be a lot of images, so i need to know a best solution for this.

Comment: Be more precise on where these images come from. From the net? Bundled with the app?

Comment: they will be bundled with app i guess...definitely not from the net. imagine if i had an apple as a part of my grocery list i would just find an image for that and add it and this image displays on the side in the apple listItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your images are bundled with the app, I'd suggest avoid reinventing the wheel and simply put your images in `res/drawable-xxx` folder, as it was designed to work on Android

Comment: what if there are too many images...around 1000?

Comment: Who told you 1000 is too many?

Comment: how many is too many for storing in resources folder?

Comment: There's no easy answer to that, as it rather depends on the app, usage and other factors, not on the android limitations

Answer (score 2):

If its a static app, i.e. its not fetching any data over the internet, then you will have to save the images in the resources folder and refer each of them using a unique name.

Comment: yes it is a static app. but will that not be too much of an overhead to store so many images in the resources folder? imagine i i have 500 fruits i will need to store 500 images

Comment: As long as your fruits aren't in 1080p, you'll probably be fine. That's what the resources folder is for, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I would store it in Sqlite DB as blob (byte array).  I will also use REST API to lazily download the images on app's first usage.  This way if you add a new product,  you don't have to issue an update of app

Comment: Dunno why that was downvoted, if the images are going to be a significant amount of space, this is a decent answer.